# How to use loess method in GGally::ggpairs using wrap function

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess, ggally

I am trying to replicate this simple example given in the Coursera R Regression Models course:

```
require(datasets)
data(swiss)
require(GGally)
require(ggplot2)
ggpairs(swiss, lower = list(continuous = "smooth", params = c(method = "loess")))
```

I expect to see a 6x6 pairs plot - one scatterplot with loess smoother and confidence intervals for each combination of the 6 variables in the swiss data.

However, I get the following error:

> Error in display_param_error() :    'params' is a deprecated argument.
>   Please 'wrap' the function to supply arguments. help("wrap", package =
>   "GGally")

I looked through the `ggpairs()` and `wrap()` help files and have tried lots of permutations of the `wrap()` and `wrap_fn_with_param_arg()` functions.

I can get this to work as expected:

```
ggpairs(swiss, lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth")))
```

But once I add the loess part in, it does not:

```
ggpairs(swiss, lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth"), method = wrap("loess")))
```

I get this error when I tried the line above.

> Error in value[3L] :    The following ggpair plot functions
>   are readily available:    continuous: c('points', 'smooth', 'density',
>   'cor', 'blank')   combo: c('box', 'dot', 'facethist', 'facetdensity',
>   'denstrip', 'blank')  discrete: c('ratio', 'facetbar', 'blank')   na:
>   c('na', 'blank')
>
> diag continuous: c('densityDiag', 'barDiag', 'blankDiag')   diag
>   discrete: c('barDiag', 'blankDiag')   diag na: c('naDiag', 'blankDiag')
>
> You may also provide your own function that follows the api of
>   function(data, mapping, ...){ . . . } and returns a ggplot2 plot
>   object    Ex:     my_fn <- function(data, mapping, ...){    p <-
>   ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
>         geom_point(...)       p     }   ggpairs(data, lower = list(continuous = my_fn))
>
> Function provided: loess

Obviously I am entering loess in the wrong place. Can anyone help me understand how to add the loess part in?

Note that my problem is different to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671686/how-to-draw-loess-estimation-in-ggally-using-ggpairs), as I am asking how to implement loess in ggpairs since the params argument became deprecated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One quick way is to write your own function... the one below was edited from the one provided by the `ggpairs` error message in your question

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)    
data(swiss)

# Function to return points and geom_smooth
# allow for the method to be changed
my_fn <- function(data, mapping, method="loess", ...){
      p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method=method, ...)
      p
    }

# Default loess curve    
ggpairs(swiss[1:4], lower = list(continuous = my_fn))
```

[image]

```
# Use wrap to add further arguments; change method to lm
ggpairs(swiss[1:4], lower = list(continuous = wrap(my_fn, method="lm")))
```

[image]

---

This perhaps gives a bit more control over the arguments that are passed to each `geon_`

```
  my_fn <- function(data, mapping, pts=list(), smt=list(), ...){
              ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
                         do.call(geom_point, pts) +
                         do.call(geom_smooth, smt) 
                 }

# Plot 
ggpairs(swiss[1:4], 
        lower = list(continuous = 
                       wrap(my_fn,
                            pts=list(size=2, colour="red"), 
                            smt=list(method="lm", se=F, size=5, colour="blue"))))
```

Comment: how do I consider a color by factor?

Comment: @Ben; if you want to split each plot by factor you  can just use `ggpairs` functionality e.g. `ggpairs(iris,  aes(col=Species), lower = list(continuous = my_fn)) `. If you want to restrict it to specific plots then you will need to extend the `my_fn` function. here are a couple of recent q and a's which should help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246984/how-to-customize-graph-with-2nd-correlation-line-in-ggpairs/66248574#66248574, or even split by group.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082421/tweaking-ggpairs-or-a-better-solution-to-a-correlation-matrix/71131736#71131736 ;

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you are taking the Coursera online course Regression Models and try to convert the Rmarkdown file given by the course to html file, and come across this error as I do.

The way I tried out is:

```
require(datasets); data(swiss); require(GGally); require(ggplot2)
g = ggpairs(swiss, lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", method = "lm")))
g
```

Also you can try using `method="loess"`, but the outcome looks a bit different from that given in the lecture. `method = "lm"` may be a better fit as I see.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this, but when I try your code, I get an error Error: Unknown parameters: method

Comment: @meenaparam In my case I've got no errors. Some `R.version` output: _platform_ `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`, _os_ `linux-gnu`, _version.string_ `R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)`.

Comment: This does work for me now, they must have updated `ggally`, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible at all to set alpha for the SE?

Comment: I have run the following code without any issue for a while. All of a sudden I am getting an error message. I have not updated myself with any recent updates in the package that could lead to this issue. Here is the code                                                                   `ggpairs(df, columns = c(2:5, 14), lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", method = "lm")),

)`. The error message is as follows: Error in wrap("smooth", method = "lm") : unused argument (method = "lm"). Can anyone shed some light as to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I suspected as well you were taking Coursera's class.
Though, I could not find any github repo containing ggplot's examples.

Here's what I did to make it work:

```
gp = ggpairs(swiss, lower = list(continuous = "smooth"))
gp
```

Comment: Thanks @Firefighter1017, but this gives an linear fit (`lm`) rather than a loess smoother as I wanted. See @scarain's answer above to make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

This works:
ggpairs(swiss, lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", method = "loess")))