# Error in stop_if_params_exist(obj$params) : 'params' is a deprecated argument

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to replicate this simple example given in the Coursera R Regression Models course:

```
gg <- ggpairs(sampledga, 
         columns = c("entropy", "length", "onegram", "threegram", "dict", "class"),
         color="class",
         lower=list(continuous="smooth", params=c(alpha=0.5)),
         diag=list(continuous="bar", combo="bar", params=c(alpha=0.5)),
         upper = list(continuous = "density", combo = "box", params=c(alpha=0.5)),
         axisLabels='show')
```

And I get the following error:

> Error in stop_if_params_exist(obj$params) : 
>     'params' is a deprecated argument.  Please 'wrap' the function to supply arguments. help("wrap", package = "GGally")
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In warn_if_args_exist(list(...)) :
>     Extra arguments: "color" are being ignored.  If these are meant to be aesthetics, submit them using the 'mapping' variable within ggpairs with ggplot2::aes or ggplot2::aes_string.

Please help me and give me a answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Or, even better, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889222/change-colors-in-ggpairs-now-that-params-is-deprecated) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085261/how-to-use-loess-method-in-ggallyggpairs-using-wrap-function).

Comment: I think I have a trouble with #lower, #diag and #upper

Comment: Precisely the `params` argument in them, see linked questions, plus the `color` won't work.

Comment: It's missing a package or library. True or False?

Comment: Please read the linked threads, they answer your question.