# Why scatter plots in ggpairs function don't have the loess layer on them?

Tags: r, loess, ggpairs

I have a quick question, and can't figure out what the problem is. I wanted to plot a dataset I have, and found one solution here:
[How to use loess method in GGally::ggpairs using wrap function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085261/how-to-use-loess-method-in-ggallyggpairs-using-wrap-function)

However, I can't seem to figure out what was wrong with my approach. Here is the code chunk below with simple mtcars dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)


View(mtcars)

GGally::ggpairs(mtcars,
                 lower= list(
                   ggplot(mapping = aes(rownames(mtcars))) + 
                     geom_point()+
                     geom_smooth(method = "loess"))
                )
```

[image]

Here, as you can see, is my output that doesn't put the smooth layer on the scatter plot. I wanted to have it for the regression analysis for my actual dataset. Any direction or explanation would be good. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mis-spell `continuous=`?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-splled it here. Sorry for that. I have put an exact code now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085261/how-to-use-loess-method-in-ggallyggpairs-using-wrap-function

Comment: Hi Edward, Thank you! yes I have looked at that. I have also put that in my question. I just don't know why I can't produce graph like in this link's answer with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the post from @Edward's comment works here with `mtcars`. The snippet below replicates your plot above, with a loess line added:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

View(mtcars)

# make a function to plot generic data with points and a loess line
my_fn <- function(data, mapping, method="loess", ...){
  p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method=method, ...)
  p
}

# call ggpairs, using mtcars as data, and plotting continuous variables using my_fn    
ggpairs(mtcars, lower = list(continuous = my_fn))
```

In your snippet, the second argument `lower` has a `ggplot` object passed to it, but what it requires is a `list` with specifically named elements, that specify what to do with specific variable types. The elements in the list can be functions or character vectors (but not `ggplot` objects). From the `ggpairs` documentation:

> upper and lower are lists that may contain the variables 'continuous',
>   'combo', 'discrete', and 'na'. Each element of the list may be a
>   function or a string. If a string is supplied, it must implement one
>   of the following options:
>
> continuous exactly one of ('points', 'smooth', 'smooth_loess',
>   'density', 'cor', 'blank'). This option is used for continuous X and Y
>   data.
>
> combo exactly one of ('box', 'box_no_facet', 'dot', 'dot_no_facet',
>   'facethist', 'facetdensity', 'denstrip', 'blank'). This option is used
>   for either continuous X and categorical Y data or categorical X and
>   continuous Y data.
>
> discrete exactly one of ('facetbar', 'ratio', 'blank'). This option is
>   used for categorical X and Y data.
>
> na exactly one of ('na', 'blank'). This option is used when all X data
>   is NA, all Y data is NA, or either all X or Y data is NA.

The reason my snippet works is because I've passed a `list` to `lower`, with an element named 'continuous' that is `my_fn` (which generates a `ggplot`).

Comment: Hi Jim, I've added the link to the question in my post, and I have been to this stack post already. I just wanted to get an explanation why my approach wasn't working and having issues. Thank you though.

Comment: hopefully that helps! fwiw i think the arguments to `ggpairs` are a bit peculiar

Comment: Thank you Jim for a nice explanation. It was weird because I was getting graph without an error. So I thought I may have been missing something minor. Nonetheless, thank you sir!